# Why is threadTerminate not called inside a dll

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a problem that code inside my dll is acting different compared to the same code within a normal application. After some debugging I found that the thread's OnTerminate is never called within the dll.

```
type
  TTest = class
  private
  public
     procedure threadStart();
     procedure threadEnd(Sender: TObject);
     procedure lines(value: String);
  end;

procedure TTest.threadStart();
var aThread : TThread;
begin
 aThread :=
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
         lines('start')
      end
    );
  aThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  aThread.OnTerminate := self.threadEnd;
  aThread.Start;
end;

procedure TTest.threadEnd;
begin
  lines('end')
end;

procedure TTest.lines(value: String);
  var MyText: TStringlist;
begin
  MyText:= TStringlist.create;
  MyText.Add(value);
  MyText.SaveToFile('.\filename.txt');
  MyText.Free
end;
```

If I run this code from a normal VLC Delphi Application, I get **end** in the text file.
If I run the same code from a dll (loading it either static or dynamic into a VLC Application), I get **start** in the text file.

My question: Why? Or better asked, how can I let my dll act the same way as my VLC. Current version I'm using is XE7.

Comment: Can duplicate in XE2, execution dies in `TMonitor.Wait(..` of `TThread.Synchronize`.

Comment: Correct, because the EXE is not looking for and processing `Synchronize()` requests from the DLL, so they are not signaled, thus `Synchronize()` blocks indefinitely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TThread.OnTerminate` event is triggered in the context of the main UI thread via a call to `TThread.Synchronize()`, which stores requests in a queue that the main UI thread checks periodically, executing pending requests when available.

If the DLL and EXE are compiled with Runtime Packages enabled, they share a single copy of the RTL (and thus require you to deploy `rtl.bpl` with your app). When the EXE checks the RTL's `Synchronize()` queue, it will see pending requests from both EXE and DLL.

However, if they are not sharing a single RTL, then they will be compiled with separate copies of the RTL that are not linked to each other.  By default, there is nothing in the EXE that checks and processes pending requests from the DLL's `Synchronize()` queue, only from the EXE's `Synchronize()` queue.  To address that, you have to export a function from the DLL that calls the `CheckSynchronize()` function of the DLL's RTL, and then make the EXE call that exported DLL function periodically, such as in a timer.

Otherwise, the other way to get around this problem is to bypass the `Synchronize()` call that triggers the `OnTerminate` event, by overriding the thread's virtual `DoTerminate()` method (which you cannot do with `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()`).  You can have `DoTerminate()` call `OnTerminate` directly, or just do what you need inside of `DoTerminate()` itself.  But either way, you have to make sure this code is thread safe, as `DoTerminate()` runs in the context of the worker thread.

Comment: Since I'm only interested when the thread is done, I think I will use a push notification to inform the main program it should call doSynchronize in the dll. This answer helped me as well to figure out a small memory leak since finished threads would never be freed as well. I prefer the simplicity of the anonymousThread over the comfort to be able to override DoTerminate. Thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: You can stick with the anonymous thread and just put your termination behaviour at the end of your anonymous method.

Comment: @Kanitatlan: just be sure to wrap the method's code in a `try/finally` block so you can perform termination logic regardless of whether an uncaught exception is raised or not. `TThread` has an internal `try/finally` around `Execute()` so `DoTerminate()` is always called.